# django rest framework Necesito enviar (key/value) en una peticion rest

Tags: django, rest, djangorestframework

buenos dias.

Estoy intentando montar un servicio que realize una accion, pero necesito pasarle a esta accion una lista de parametros.
Pongo un ejempo:

```
{
"to":"usuario",
"params":[{"key":"numero","value":"9"},{"Contrato","AB90"}]
}
```

Mi problema es que no puedo serializar este elemento.
Alguna idea que me pueda orientar?

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: algo como `return Response({"data": "data"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)` ?

Comment: En tu serializador puede añadir un campo de tipo [MethodSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), django rest llamara a esta función en tu serializador, desde esa función puedes construir los datos a tu manera.